# JavaScript/jQuery and customized form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, input, niceforms

Hallo everyone,

stackoverflow has always been a good resource for programming related questions. This is the first time I ask a question by mysqlf, as I absolutely can't find a good solution. So please forgive me if I forgot anything - I'm willing to learn ;-)

I've used JS and jQuery for a long time now. The benefit of jQuery is, that there are lot's of resources and plugins for various needs you can use out of the box.
However, I see lots of websites using quite nice form elements (Styled inputs for: text/password, radio, checkboxes, dropdowns, etc). But I couldn't find any jQuery plugin or JavaScript framework, which provides the possibility to design/style form elements. Either they lack of element support or they're very unstable.

- jQuery UI (which I've recently started to use) doesn't support text-inputs and drop down menus.
- NiceForms is quite neat, but it's a little bit unstable in some browsers and rather hacky. It replaces some elements with various absolute positioned divs, which sometimes completely destroys my layout or just doesn't work (while floating etc.). Also it lacks lots of basic attributes like the width of some elements.

I'm looking for a way to style them graphically. So I don't want to just modify its borders via CSS. Do you know any resources, I can use for that?
I'd code it myself, but I'm a bit afraid of the huge work, as it can be very nerve-wracking to make customized form fields work on all the common browsers.

Does anyone know some other (still maintained or stable) approaches than jQuery UI and NiceForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Think again

Are there any particular reasons to style form elements outside of CSS capabilities which are growing in time (think of CSS3) and would actually **benefit form usability**? What kind of styling would you like to do that can't be done by CSS?

**On more thing:** I suggest you think of your users that are used to the usual HTML form elements and their functionality as well as how they appear on screen. If you'd completely change the way they look, it could mean that your form would make it much worse from the usability point of view. So some styling is OK, too much of it may make your form unusable.

But if it's just custom form fields that you're after, you can get them usually as jQuery plugins, but they are usually based on existing HTML input elements.

### Rich functionality alternative with consistent styling

But if you're asking about rich form capabilities there's always [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/) which is very consistently styled and provides lots and lots (and even more) elements and capabilities. And is very very professionally made (it's been very good since 2.0 and it's just getting better).

Comment: I agree that styled input elements (styled beyond what css can do) are the wrong thing to do 95% of the time. Considering you can round borders, change bg colour, add shadows etc with css - using jquery to do this is a prety bad idea unless you are 100% sure about quality control and testing

Comment: I got the impression the author was asking due to consistency reasons. I've seen ExtJS before, looks pretty nice -- but that said, is not FOSS (and fairly expensive to use commercially at that). It's a reasonable question, in my mind -- manually styling forms across browsers can take quite a long time and sometimes you just need a quick way of dealing with some client shrieking "MAKE IT PRETTIER!!!" at you... Just my two. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got to admit, I agree with you. I think I'll stick with CSS3 and style them the "valid" way. I was just hoping, there was a nice way to also support IE6 and the like without having to write and debug various different stylesheets. The only thing I thought of in this case was replacing <input>-fields and restructuring them using graphics. However, I think using CSS3 and showing "regular" input fields for older browsers should do it anyway. Thanks :-)

Comment: @aendrew: That's true but on professional (paid) projects ExtJS price is more than acceptable. They used to have a licence for open-source projects as well but I don't know whether they still have that or not.

Comment: @mario: Since you've mentioned IE6: I suggest you check your logs how many users actually still use it. Checking [my blog](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com) analytics I can say that there's only 0.3% of users in the last month that used IE6. I don't think it's worth the effort to support them. Forms will work for them just as well. They'll just look a bit different. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions out there... [Here are 25 of them](http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a metric tonne of jQuery plugins to style forms:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/08/26/20-jquery-plugins-and-tutorials-to-enhance-forms/

Also this:
http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/

Boom! 50+ form skinning jQuery plugins!
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/09/50-jquery-plugins-for-form-enhancements.html

From the above, [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) looks nifty. Here's a tutorial on using it:
http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-skin-html-form-elements-in.html

Comment: Thanks aendrew and gearsdigital. I appreciate your help and pointing me to those articles. But I was rather hopig to get some feedback in case you have already used some of them. Most of the plugins/extensions don't cover more than a few input fields. But I'll give some of them a try!